# Is there an overview of all codes that can be used inside NSLog()?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, nslog

i.e. %@ for strings, %f for doubles... I don't know the word for these placeholders but it would be great to have list for how to print booleans and other values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `NSLog` takes a `NSString` as its argument, it uses the `NSString` format specifiers.  This is virtually identical to the common `printf` specifiers.  Also, the `%@` specifier is not limited to `NSString` objects, but is for any Objective-C objects.  The base `NSObject` class provides a generic description of the object consisting of its class and its address, but many objects will supply information specific to their type, such as the collection classes (`NSArray`, `NSDictionary`) which will supply nicely formated dump of their contents.  You can provide this for your own objects that you create by overriding `-description` (see the documentation for more info, including localization capability).

See also: [NSString Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)

Comment: "%@" isn't valid for any Objective-C object, only objects that respond to "description". If I were to create my own object deriving from Object (declared in "objc/Object.h"), it won't necessarily be compatible with "%@".

Comment: This is true, even though that is what the `NSString Format Specifiers` documentation defines it as. Even adding `description` is not enough if you're building your own root class.

Answer (score 3):

It is a normal C format string with the extension of %@ (which prints any NSObject by querying its -description method, not just NSStrings).

You can see an overview in printf [manpage](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/printf.3.html)

Comment: It is a normal C format string with the exception of the (evil) %n conversion specifier. It's not working in objective-C format strings.

Answer (score 2):

Also, there's a very nice overview, as well as some tips and tricks, in the most recent "Friday Q&A" posting on Mike Ash's NSBlog blog:

http://www.mikeash.com/?page=pyblog/friday-qa-2009-07-17-format-strings-tips-and-tricks.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little snapshot from "Programming in Objective-C 2.0"

[alt text http://img361.imageshack.us/img361/1438/picture1rze.png](http://img361.imageshack.us/img361/1438/picture1rze.png)