# Symbols in Obj-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sdk

What are all of the symbols in obj-c? Like %@, %d, etc. What do they all mean? Thanks

Comment: Is this site broken? http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html

Comment: There are tons of them. Which set of symbols are you referring to? Your question seems to be asking about `NSString stringWithFormat:`.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [Is there an overview of all codes that can be used inside NSLog()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153003/is-there-an-overview-of-all-codes-that-can-be-used-inside-nslog)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`%@` and `%d` are [format specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1).

- see also http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html

> `NSString` supports the format characters defined for the ANSI C function `printf()`, plus `@` for **any object**. If the object responds to the `descriptionWithLocale:` message, `NSString` sends that message to retrieve the text representation, otherwise, it sends a description message.

See also: [Apple Documentation – FormatStrings.html](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html)

Answer (score 2):

These are known as format specifiers. Obj-C has a number of format specifiers; I have mentioned some in the example below, along with the output:

```
NSString * name=@"XYZ";
NSLog(@"Name=%@",name);

int count=100;
NSLog(@"Count=%d",count);

Float number=555.55;
NSLog(@"number=%f",number);
```

Output will be:

```
Name=XYZ
Count=100
number=555.5549
```

Answer (score 1):

They are called [Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).

Answer (score 1):

They are format specifiers. Each type is for a different type of variable. For instance `%i` is for `int` type integers.

```
int theInteger = 25;
NSLog(@"The integer is = %i", theInteger);
```

Will print, *'The integer is = 25'*. All others are for different types of stored variable. Except for the `%@`. The `%@` specifier means object. Which can be things like `NSStrings`, `NSArray`. And pretty much anything subclassed under NSObject.

```
NSString *stringObject = [[NSString alloc]initWithString@"The String"];
NSlog(@"The string is = %@", stringObject);
```

You will not understand the latter until you understand objects. I recommend picking up a good book on Obj-C. **'Programming in Objective-C'** by *Stephen G*. Kochan is a good start and will explain objects well.

Answer (score 0):

The best response is in the [Mac Os X Refrence library](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1).

The big difference between C and Objective C is the %@ symbols. The %@ print as string the return of  descriptionWithLocale of an object if available.

Comment: Funny, all this time I thought the big difference between C and Objective-C was that Objective-C had an object system...